# NextJS Build failing AWS Amplify - Required dependency file not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, vercel, next.js13

We are experiencing a build error on our project hosted with AWS Amplify. Our project, which was previously working and deploying successfully, is now failing during the build phase without any changes in our codebase.

The error message we receive during the build process is as follows:

`CustomerError: Required dependency file not found: /codebuild/output/src1250669152/src/tsv-webapp/amplify.sh`

This issue occurs after the caching phase and appears to be tied to the AWS environment not being able to locate the amplify.sh file.

This issue has been referred in github as-well.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3615

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3631

```
2023-08-04T04:25:20.021Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
2023-08-04T04:25:20.023Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2023-08-04T04:25:20.101Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2023-08-04T04:25:20.110Z [INFO]: # Creating cache artifact...
2023-08-04T04:25:29.417Z [INFO]: # Created cache artifact
2023-08-04T04:25:29.502Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
2023-08-04T04:25:34.357Z [INFO]: # Uploaded cache artifact
2023-08-04T04:25:34.448Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2023-08-04T04:25:34.452Z [INFO]: Setting NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE=true to produce .next/standalone directory
2023-08-04T04:25:34.455Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
2023-08-04T04:25:37.928Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Required dependency file not found: /codebuild/output/src1250669152/src/tsv-webapp/amplify.sh
2023-08-04T04:25:37.985Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-08-04T04:25:37.985Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

We're hoping for assistance in troubleshooting this issue and identifying if there have been any recent changes in AWS that could be causing this sudden build error.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am hitting the same exact issue ^, and I am unable to move fwd in debugging - as the logs are not clear.